# How can I calculate the run-time complexity of this flatten array function if number of items is unknown?

Tags: python, arrays, big-o, flatten

I have a function flattens given array.

```
def flatten(items):
    results = []
    for i in items:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            results += flatten(i)
        else:
            results.append(i)
    return results
```

It works great. It is not possible to know how many times it will run when I give an input as shown below. There are a lot of nested arrays.

```
data = [1, 2, 3, [4], [5, 6], [[7, 8, 9], 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, [[[16], 17], 18, 19], [[[20, 21]]]], [[[22], 23, [[24]]]]]
data_flatten = flatten(data)

print(data_flatten)
```

I have no idea how can I calculate the run-time complexity of this function?

Answer (score 3):

Since, I'm assuming, you care about the worst case performance, you can consider an abstract worst case example and then derive the answer from that.

`data = [[[[... [1, 2, 3, ..., m] ...]]], [[[... [1, 2, 3, ..., m] ...]]], ..., [[[... [1, 2, 3, ..., m] ...]]]]`

Now you can easily see how the worst case is influenced by three factors. The size of `items`, the depth of the list of lists, and finally the number of elements in a deepest list.

The worst case complexity thus is `O(n x d x m)` where `n`, `d`, and `m` stand for the size of `items`, the maximum depth of the nested lists, and the maximum number of elements in a deepest list.

Answer (score 0):

Exact size isn't really too important when it comes to complexity.   Constants get dropped anyway.  If you have a 3d array, internally it has to loop through all the items, even if that's not obvious by the code.   So the answer is O(n**3) because it needs a loop inside a loop inside a loop.   The exact value of what n means doesn't matter because constants get dropped.